# Need help making a data table from \plot function in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

I want to be able to generate a list of points from a plot in Tikz, with an adjustable interval and range for the x-values. 
So basically something like this:

```
++++++++++++++
+            +
+     ^      +
+    / \     +
+   /   \    +
+  /     \   +
++++++++++++++

 X | Y 
-------
-3 | 1 
-2 | 2 
-1 | 3 
0  | 4 
1  | 3 
2  | 2 
2  | 1
```

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\definecolor{abmorange}{HTML}{F7D700}
\definecolor{abmred}{HTML}{EB5448}
\definecolor{abmblue}{HTML}{2C90C6}
\definecolor{abmgreen}{HTML}{9DAB6F}
\definecolor{abmcream}{HTML}{FEFEDD}
\definecolor{abmyellow}{HTML}{EEEE00}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.4} 

\tikzset{
  dim above/.style={to path={\pgfextra{
        \pgfinterruptpath
        \draw[>=latex,|<->|,black!50] let
        \p1=($(\tikztostart)!2mm!90:(\tikztotarget)$),
        \p2=($(\tikztotarget)!2mm!-90:(\tikztostart)$)
        in(\p1) -- (\p2) node[fill=black!5,pos=.5,sloped,above,font=\sffamily]{#1};
        \endpgfinterruptpath
      }
    }
  },
  dim below/.style={to path={\pgfextra{
        \pgfinterruptpath
        \draw[>=latex,|<->|,black!50] let 
        \p1=($(\tikztostart)!2mm!90:(\tikztotarget)$),
        \p2=($(\tikztotarget)!2mm!-90:(\tikztostart)$)
        in (\p1) -- (\p2) node[pos=.5,sloped,below,font=\sffamily]{#1};
        \endpgfinterruptpath
      }
    }
  },
}

\newenvironment{plots}[2][10]{
\begin{figure}\centering
\caption{#2}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis x line= middle, axis y line= middle, width=\textwidth, samples=50,grid=both, domain=-10:10, xmin=-#1, xmax=#1, ymin=-#1, ymax=#1, ultra thick, scale only axis, enlargelimits=false, anchor=origin, disabledatascaling]
}{
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
}

\newcommand{\func}[2][abmblue]{\addplot[color=#1] {#2};}

\newcommand{\parfunc}[3][abmblue]{\addplot[color=#1,domain=-200:200] ({#2},{#3});}
\begin{document}
\begin{plots}{Parametric Function of a Hyperbola}
\parfunc{2+4/cos(x)}{-3+3*tan(x)}
\end{plots}
\end{document}
```

An additional note: I have figured out how to do a table using \foreach:

```
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=3} 
\makeatletter 
\let\globalappendtomacro=\pgfutil@g@addto@macro 
\makeatother 
\def\something{}
\foreach \i in {0,\the\numexpr2\relax,...,20}{
\pgfmathparse{cos(\i)}
\edef\temp{\i & \pgfmathresult\noexpand\\} 
\expandafter\globalappendtomacro\expandafter\something\expandafter{\temp}
} 

\begin{tabular}{rr} 
\something
\end{tabular}
```

However, I have no clue how I would insert a parametric function into the \pgfmathparse{} command.

Comment: So you have the function and you want to evaluate it at certain points and print that as a table?

Comment: Maybe you could post your TikZ code!? Your question is not easy to understand.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  This is doable, depending on _how_ you are doing the plot, so it would be best if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.

Comment: @Jake exactly. I can post a mwe real quick.

Comment: I feel that you are looking for something like `function graph cut` from `pgfplotstable` but I don't know if your X values are given or computed. I mean are they the `x` values or the arguments of `2+4/cos(x)=-3` etc.?

Comment: I want to be able to set the x-value range and step, e.g., -10 to 10, step of 2, would get values -10, -8, -6, -4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, and 10. I want a function similar to that of a TI-84 calculator, where you plot a graph and can then look at a table for certain values. I hope that helps.

Comment: I think I'm still misunderstanding the question but `\pgfplotstablenew[create on use/X/.style={create col/set list={-3,...,3}},
create on use/Y1/.style={create col/expr={2+4/cos(\thisrow{X} r)}},
create on use/Y2/.style={create col/expr={-3+3*tan(\thisrow{X} r)}},
columns={X,Y1,Y2},
]{7}{\mytable}
\pgfplotstabletypeset\mytable` looks like what you are describing via `pgfplotstable` package.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that the following is an answer to the question.

I've created a table from scratch to populate the function entries via having an array of values in column `X` and evaluation of the array via `Y1` and `Y2` columns with the functions given in the question.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstablenew[
create on use/X/.style={create col/set list={-3,...,3}}, 
create on use/Y1/.style={create col/expr={2+4/cos(\thisrow{X} r)}}, 
create on use/Y2/.style={create col/expr={-3+3*tan(\thisrow{X} r)}}, 
columns={X,Y1,Y2}, ]{7}{\mytable} 

\pgfplotstabletypeset\mytable
\end{document}
```

[image]